# Remove particular query string from url in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.x

I know that my question title sounds like duplicate but it's not. Our project is multi-lingual. I have listing page on this page cakephp pagination is applied. But the link on pagination number is :

```
http://example.com/controller/action?language=en&page=8
```

I've implemented routing to disappear action, using below mentioned routing code:

```
$routes->connect('/controller', 
               ['language' => 'en', 'controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action']
    );
```

so now it is :

```
http://example.com/controller?language=en&page=8
```

But my requirement is like this

```
http://example.com/controller?page=8
```

To achieve my goal, I have implemented this code

```
$routes->connect('/controller/:page', 
           ['language' => 'en', 'controller' => 'controller', 'action' => 'action'], ['page' => "(?page:'[0-9]+]')"]
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also i need same thing...

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to tweak the `PaginatorHelper` settings to pass the `language` parameter to its links.

```
$this->Paginator->options([
    'url' => [
        'language' => 'en'
    ]
]);
```

See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#configuring-pagination-options